# Using iteration dynamically build Criteria Block

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I want to query Attributes based on several filters and build the criteria dynamically

```
Domain Class
PatientAttr {
   def name
   def value
}
```

**Criteria Building code**

```
    if(filters.size() != 0 ){
        def criteria =  PatientAttr.createCriteria()
        def results = criteria.list{
            for (item in filters){
                def name = item.name
                def filter = item.filter
                and{
                    eq 'name', name
                    if(filter[0] == "lt")
                        lt ('value', filter[1] as Double)
                    else if(filter[0] == "gt")
                        gt ('value', filter[1] as Double)
                    else 
                        between ('value', filter[0] as Double, filter[1] as Double)
                }
            }
        }
```

What I find is that only the last "and" statement of the list is being evaluated. Does criteria builder allow you to build criteria dynamically?

The code above should be equivalent to this

```
        def results = criteria.list{
            and{
                eq 'name', "Serum albumin (g/dL)"
                gt 'value', 3.5 as Float
            }
            and{    
                eq 'name', "M-spike (g/dL)"
                gt 'value', 2.3 as Float
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about why you are having trouble, but since the default conjunction for queries is `and`, there's no reason to use an `and{}` closure in your example at all.  Your query above is the same as:

```
    def results = criteria.list{
        eq 'name', "Serum albumin (g/dL)"
        gt 'value', 3.5 as Float
        eq 'name', "M-spike (g/dL)"
        gt 'value', 2.3 as Float
    }
```

If you want the top-leve items `or`'d together, then you need to wrap the outer block in an `or{}` closure:

```
if(filters.size() != 0 ){
    def criteria =  PatientAttr.createCriteria()
    def results = criteria.list{
        or{
            for (item in filters){
                def name = item.name
                def filter = item.filter
                and{
                    eq 'name', name
                    if(filter[0] == "lt")
                        lt ('value', filter[1] as Double)
                    else if(filter[0] == "gt")
                        gt ('value', filter[1] as Double)
                    else 
                        between ('value', filter[0] as Double, filter[1] as Double)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This will return a query with the results like:

> name is 'Serum albumin...' and value is greater than '3.5'
>   *OR*
>   name is 'M-spike...' and value is greater than 2.3
>   *OR etc*

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: def results = criteria.list{
        eq 'name', "Serum albumin (g/dL)"
        gt 'value', 3.5 as Float
        eq 'name', "M-spike (g/dL)"
        gt 'value', 2.3 as Float
    }

Answer (score 0):

by your block:

```
    def results = criteria.list{
        and{
            eq 'name', "Serum albumin (g/dL)"
            gt 'value', 3.5 as Float
        }
        and{    
            eq 'name', "M-spike (g/dL)"
            gt 'value', 2.3 as Float
        }
    }
```

do you mean to express:

```
((name == "Serum albumin (g/dL)") or (value == 3.5))
and
((name == "M-spike (g/dL)") or (value == 3.3))
```

Then your code should be:

```
if(filters.size() != 0 ){
    def criteria =  PatientAttr.createCriteria()
    def results = criteria.list{
        and{
            for (item in filters){
                def name = item.name
                def filter = item.filter
                or {
                    eq 'name', name
                    if(filter[0] == "lt")
                        lt ('value', filter[1] as Double)
                    else if(filter[0] == "gt")
                        gt ('value', filter[1] as Double)
                    else 
                        between ('value', filter[0] as Double, filter[1] as Double)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

if you mean to express:

```
((name == "Serum albumin (g/dL)") and (value == 3.5))
and
((name == "M-spike (g/dL)") and (value == 3.3))
```

Then your code should be:

```
if(filters.size() != 0 ){
    def criteria =  PatientAttr.createCriteria()
    def results = criteria.list{
        and{
            for (item in filters){
                def name = item.name
                def filter = item.filter
                eq 'name', name
                if(filter[0] == "lt")
                    lt ('value', filter[1] as Double)
                else if(filter[0] == "gt")
                    gt ('value', filter[1] as Double)
                else 
                    between ('value', filter[0] as Double, filter[1] as Double)
            }
        }
    }
```

because and is the default operation, you can omit the and method.